# bash stdout some information and pipe other from inside loop

Tags: bash, loops, pipe

How to print output from a loop which is piped to some other command:

```
for f in "${!myList[@]}"; do 
    echo $f > /dev/stdout # echoed to stdout, how to?
    unzip -qqc $f # piped to awk script
done | awk -f script.awk
```

Comment: With Linux: `echo "$f" >&255`

Comment: @Cyrus doesn't work but `echo "$f" >&2` work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `/dev/stderr` or second file descriptor:

```
echo something >&2 | grep nothing
echo something >/dev/stderr | grep nothing
```

You can use another file descriptor that will be connected to stdout:

```
# for a single command group
{ echo something >&3 | grep nothing; } 3>&1
# or for everywhere
exec 3>&1
echo something >&3 | grep nothing
# same as above with named file descriptor
exec {LOG}>&1
echo 123 >&$LOG | grep nothing
```

You can also redirect the output to current controlling terminal `/dev/tty` (if there is one):

```
echo something >/dev/tty | grep nothing
```